# Searching IntelliJ / Android Studio using cmd-shift-f injects random characters into search box

Tags: jetbrains-ide

For the last six months I have had the most annoying issue with IntelliJ (Android Studio), every time I press `cmd-shift-f` to do a global search the search box will come up, then about one second later a bunch of random characters will appear in the box. To make matters worse if you type text into the box anything you type will be overwritten. I have no idea what is causing it, putting the random string into Google yields no results however it is the same string every time. Over time I have just learned to wait until the characters appear, then I remove them and type my query but this is killing my workflow. I keep checking Google and Stack Overflow every so often but have found nothing.

[image: Screenshot of what is normally seen, got the string from Google]

Answer (score 4):

This morning I pressed the `cmd-shift-f` key combination to search and I spotted a GPGTools dialog briefly appear. It turns out GPG tools was trying to inject my fingerprint this whole time. The combination `cmd-shift-f` is used by GPGTools, and once I knew what to search for I found this post that fixed the issue:

> GPGServices had a binding for the key combo in question (Cmd-Shift-F),
>   which happened to be "OpenPGP: Insert my fingerprint." I don't think I
>   mentioned it before, but that's actually what the surprising dialog
>   did: inserted the fingerprint of whatever key I picked into the
>   "what-to-search-for" field of the IntelliJ search dialog. And to
>   confirm the diagnosis, unchecking this setting in the SysPrefs
>   Keyboard Shortcuts does keep the dialog from appearing.

https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/51070-gpgservices-spurious-select-key-dialog

[image]